# nested list comprehension to achieve nested lists

Tags: python, list, nltk, list-comprehension

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

list1 =['This is text','This is another text']
stp = stopwords.words('English')

lower_token =  [t.lower().split() for t in list1]


new2=[]
for list in lower_token:
  new1=[]
  for word in list:
    if word not in stp:
      new1.append(word)
  new2.append(new1)

new2
```

> > [['text'], ['another', 'text']]

In the above conditional loop, I am trying to `split the text` into two list and then exclude any word that occurs in `stp` list. Although I was able to achieve the results using for loop, but I am interested to achieve the same using a list comprehension, but I failed to do.

here is my unsuccessful effort using list comprehension

`[word for list in lower_token for word in list if word not in stp]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close, you just need to put the inner list comprehension in brackets too. That also makes it more readable.

```
[[word for word in txt.lower().split() if word not in stp] for txt in list1]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to enclose the inner comprehension as list too.

`[[word for word in list if word not in stp] for list in lower_token]`